# How to SELECT DISTINCT another column in SQL, by rows with MAX(Column value)

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, self-join

How to Select Distinct another column reference from rows with have MAX(Column) value.
This my table:

```
Category |  Desc  | Total1 | Total2 |  MaxDate   | Topic
--------------------------------------------------------
   A     | A Desc |   1    |    3   | 2017-04-01 | Topic1
   A     | A Desc |   1    |    1   | 2017-05-10 | Topic2
   B     | B Desc |   1    |    1   | 2017-03-25 | Topic3
```

I want to select `Topic` column for reference max value from `MaxDate` column. I want table to be like:

```
Category |  Desc  | Total1 | Total2 |  MaxDate   | Topic
--------------------------------------------------------
   A     | A Desc |   2    |    4   | 2017-05-10 | Topic2
   B     | B Desc |   1    |    1   | 2017-03-25 | Topic3
```

Then `Total1` and `Total2` is value from SUM rows have distinct

Comment: @stvfns please check the answer and let me know if any further help needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basing on your data in this way also we can achieve

```
Declare @Table1  TABLE 
    (Category varchar(1), Descp varchar(6), Total1 int, Total2 int, MaxDate datetime, Topic varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Category, Descp, Total1, Total2, MaxDate, Topic)
VALUES
    ('A', 'A Desc', 1, 3, '2017-04-01 00:00:00', 'Topic1'),
    ('A', 'A Desc', 1, 1, '2017-05-10 00:00:00', 'Topic2'),
    ('B', 'B Desc', 1, 1, '2017-03-25 00:00:00', 'Topic3')
;
```

**SCRIPT**

```
Select TT.Category,
   TT.Descp,
   TT.Total1,
   TT.Total2,
   TT.MaxDate,
   T.Topic 
            From @Table1 T
   INNER JOIN (
   select 
        Category,Descp,
            SUM(Total1)Total1,
            SUM(Total2)Total2,
            Max(MaxDate)MaxDate 
                    from @Table1
   GROUP BY  Category,Descp )TT
   ON T.MaxDate = TT.MAXDATE
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the simple way. I don't understand using partition like in another answer

Comment: @mohan111  I think your `ON` clause should be `ON T.MaxDate = TT.MAXDATE and T.category = TT.category)

Comment: @Stfvns: Then try to learn how to use them, I added some references in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Use could use [row_number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) and [sum() over()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) like this

```
  DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
  (
      Category varchar(10),  [Desc]  varchar(20), Total1 int, Total2 int,  MaxDate datetime, Topic varchar(10)
  )

  INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES
 ('A','A Desc', 1, 3, '2017-04-01', 'Topic1'),
 ('A','A Desc', 1, 1, '2017-05-10', 'Topic2'),
 ('B','B Desc', 1, 1, '2017-03-25', 'Topic3')

 ;WITH temp AS
 (
   SELECT  sd.Category, sd.MaxDate, sd.Topic, sd.[Desc], 
         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY sd.Category ORDER BY sd.MaxDate desc) AS Rn,
         Sum(sd.Total1) OVER(PARTITION BY sd.Category ) AS Total1,
         Sum(sd.Total2) OVER(PARTITION BY sd.Category ) AS Total2
   FROM @SampleData sd
 )
 SELECT t.Category, t.[Desc], t.Total1,t.Total2, t.MaxDate, t.ToPic
 FROM temp t
 WHERE t.Rn = 1
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/NQI25173